# Yii2 + SQLite. php yii migrate can access db file, while controller can't

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, yii

I have strange error on custom controller `SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file` which mean that SQLite pdo could not open db file.

However if I run `yii` commands in cli, there is no problem with db, and I can confirm that file is accessed and modified properly.

So how can it work, and not work at the same time? Is Yii using different dbs for `cli` and for app served with `php yii serve`? How could I debug which settings Yii is using to connect to db?

Edit:
I'm using basic template. So `/config/console.php` reuse db definitions in `/config/db.php`. There is also `/config/test_db.php` which also reuse `db.php` but with different filename. I'm able to run migrations from cli on it too.

Edit2:
**Console.php**

```
<?php

$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');
$db = require(__DIR__ . '/db.php');

$config = [
    'id' => 'basic-console',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'app\commands',
    'components' => [
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'log' => [
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'db' => $db,
    ],
    'params' => $params,
    /*
    'controllerMap' => [
        'fixture' => [ // Fixture generation command line.
            'class' => 'yii\faker\FixtureController',
        ],
    ],
    */
];

if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
    ];
}

return $config;
```

**web.php**

```
<?php

$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');

$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => '55XZP22thd9CwL_fvERZXAkFGOtqIxtp',
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            '<?php

$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');

$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => '55XZP22thd9CwL_fvERZXAkFGOtqIxtp',
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => true,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),
        /*
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
            ],
        ],
        */
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];

if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
        // uncomment the following to add your IP if you are not connecting from localhost.
        //'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1'],
    ];

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
        // uncomment the following to add your IP if you are not connecting from localhost.
        //'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1'],
    ];
}

return $config;

useFileTransport' => true,
    ],
    'log' => [
        'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
        'targets' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),
    /*
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
        ],
    ],
    */
],
'params' => $params,
];

if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
// configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
$config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
$config['modules']['debug'] = [
    'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
    // uncomment the following to add your IP if you are not connecting from localhost.
    //'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1'],
];

$config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
$config['modules']['gii'] = [
    'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
    // uncomment the following to add your IP if you are not connecting from localhost.
    //'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1'],
];
}

return $config;
```

**db.php**

```
<?php

return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'sqlite:/path/to/db.sqlite',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Yii2 use different configuration  for console and applications

for console  see

```
/console/config/main.php
```

or

```
/console/config/main-local.php
```

for the app assuming you are using advanced  template check  eg:

```
/yourapp/frontent/config/main.php
```

or main-local.php

and check for db componentents content

Comment: console configs reuse db.php, so it should have exact same config like controllers, right? (I've added some more info in edit to my question)

Comment: then update your question and add .. the config/web.php and console.php please